# How to get method parameters types in live templates in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, groovy, live-templates

I want to create a live template for [Timber logger](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) similarly to default live template **logm** . It uses a Groovy script to collect method parameters and separate them by commas. For example:

```
public int func(int a, float b, Object c, String d) {
    logm
}
```

generate the following code:

```
public int func(int a, float b, Object c, String d) {
    Log.d(TAG, "func() called with: a = [" + a + "], b = [" + b + "], c = [" + c + "], d = [" + d + "]");
}
```

Parameters are collecting by the following code:

```
def params = _2.collect {it + ' = [" + ' + it + ' + "]'}.join(', ');
return '"' + _1 + '() called' + (params.empty  ? '' : ' with: ' + params) + '"'

//Where _1 and _2 - default IDEA methods, in this case 
//_1 - methodName(), which eturns the name of the embracing method (where the template is expanded).
//_2 - methodParameters(), which returns the list of parameters of the embracing method (where the template is expanded).
```

The problem is the Timber methods require type format for parameters, for example:

```
int a = 5;
String s = new String("test");
boolean b = false;

Timber.d("%d, %s, %b", a, s, b);
```

Thus, i need to determine the types of method parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating live template with cursor at % types, and fill them after using this template